# error connecting to analysis servives from asp.net app on another machine

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ssas

I have been tasked with getting a asp.net (vb.net) talking to an analysis services engine on our production servers. The web server is a separate machine from the web server. The web server runs as the IUSR_ user. The application (of course) works on the development machine which has both IIS and Analysis services on it. The problem I see appears to be a permissions error (returned in the browser by the asp.net app):

```
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host ....
```

it is described in a similar post here: http://www.mydatabasesupport.com/forums/sqlserver-olap/201903-existing-connection-forcibly-closed-remote-host.html

I am not a system admin, nor am I an expert in analysis services (why have I been tasked with this you ask? because other people haven't been able to get it working and it has fallen on me). Anyway, I could use some help ... I have tried creating and adding the user (IUSR_) to the sql server and added that user to the role. While that worked on my local machine, it did not work in our production environment where the sql and web servers are separate.

tia,
Don

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well after some fiddling i came up with something that works. its probably not a huge security concern because this server is not visible to the public internet; it is visible only to a couple iis servers (it is not on our lan) - this is, however, a 'brute-force', non-secure solution (in some environments anyway)  ...

1. ON THE IIS SERVER: added this to the connection string in web config: SSPI=anonymous; this turns on an unauthenticated access request.
2. ON THE SQL SERVER: in analysis services, right click on the server. under "general" go near the bottom to "Security\RequireClientAuthentication" and change it to False
3. same page, select "security" on the left (instead of general). Add "ANONYMOUS LOGIN" to the list of users
4. get out of the server properties. right click on the CubeViewer role in the cube and choose properties. Add ANONYMOUS LOGIN to the list of users.

so, i have unauthenticated access from our iis server to the sql server.

i'd still be interested in seeing a more secure solution - oh, and i forgot to mention, there is no domain ... these are two servers on the same subnet with only regular logins.